# Prevent accessing files in Drupal files folder directly by following link

Tags: users, files

I have member area on my site, and there i have files available only to members. (also, not to all members, but to members of some role, and also they are further granulated by field condition, but that is a long story :)

But technically, anyone can download a file, if knowing the link to the file.

I would like to prevent downloading files by direct link, or by being logged of site.

It would be perfect if i can execute a script when someone asks for file by direct linking, to check if user is logged in, if he has a role that grants him download.

But if that is not possible, i would like to disable accessing files directly, they should be only accessible by browsing the site.

Thanks for clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7)

> Control access to private file downloads and specify HTTP headers.
>
> This hook allows modules enforce permissions on file downloads when
>   the private file download method is selected. Modules can also provide
>   headers to specify information like the file's name or MIME type.

Comment: Thanks! How is private file download method selected ? My files are stored in public folder, though.

Comment: Have a look at the API. It sais: "If the user does not have permission to access the file, return -1". So it's up to you to return -1 whenever you think that a user should not access that particular file. Also, files in the public:// folder go through Drupal and this hook as well.

Comment: @cherouvim public files don't go through Drupal, they are served by web server. Thus, this hook won't be called for public files.