# Disallow access to member files when they are in public file system

Tags: files

I have case where I want to make it impossible for the users to access file directly (http://www.mydomain.com/members/file.pdf), but want to allow downloading this file only if link is displayed on Drupal page, that user has privilege to see.

I know it can be easily done if those files are outside webroot and defined as private filesystem.

But is there any alternative solution, Apache way, php/Drupal way to achieve this for files that are not in private filesystem?

Those member files are of various extensions, so I could not just disallow by extension.

I have asked [simmilar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/prevent-accessing-files-in-drupal-files-folder-directly-by-following-link) before, but as I understood, proposed `hook_file_download` way works only for private file system setup.

Comment: Drupal has a built-in private file system, which can be easily customised in code. Have a look at [Working with files in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file) for a bit more info, it might come in useful

Comment: tnx clive, actually im using it for some other case on the same site. But now i face a need to protect very big structure of files that are under standard filesystem. I can migrate them to private, but it will require lots of work. As i hold apache in my hands also, im hoping to have chance to protect them in place if possible/ reliable.

Answer (score 1):

To Apache or any other web server, seeing

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg">
```

in html and a user typing `http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg` into their browser directly is basically the same thing so the quick answer is "no, not really, at least from a drupal standpoint."  You could obfuscate the path with some javascript trickery but that's about it.

Now, you could look into Apache referrer access, a quick link about [allowing access from specific referrers](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=9786) might shed some possibilities on it for you, but now you are certainly outside of drupal :)